# install Boost.MPI in a directory without administration privileges

Tags: boost, boost-mpi

How can I install Boost.MPI in my home directory without having any administrative privileges on the Unix system I am working on?

Answer (score 1):

As explicitly mentioned in the [Boost Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install), pass `--prefix` when invoking bootstrap.sh to specify your intended installation destination:

> Unless you have write permission in your system's `/usr/local/` directory, you'll probably want to at least use
>
> ```
> $ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/installation/prefix
> ```
>
> to install somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks ildjarn. Building this way couldn't install Boost.MPI. whenever I compile any program with mpi I get errors like: undefined reference to `boost::mpi::communicator::communicator()'

Comment: "*Building this way couldn't install Boost.MPI*" What was b2/bjam's output? Why didn't it build?

Comment: here is a sample error from bjam: _In file included from ./boost/mpi/allocator.hpp:15:0,
                 from ./boost/mpi.hpp:22,
                 from ./boost/graph/distributed/mpi_process_group.hpp:30,
                 from libs/graph_parallel/src/mpi_process_group.cpp:14:
./boost/mpi/config.hpp:20:17: schwerwiegender Fehler: mpi.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Kompilierung beendet._    **translation: mpi.h not found, compilation terminated**

Comment: @Tarek : That means your MPI compiler wasn't found. I assume you have LAM/MPI, MPICH, or OpenMPI installed? If so, then follow [the configuration instructions from the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html#mpi.config); if not, then you need to install an MPI compiler before building Boost.MPI.

Comment: I do have OpenMPI, and its module is already loaded. I don't have bjam installed and I am stuck at this step: _Information about building Boost.Jam is available here. However, most users need only run build.sh in the tools/build/jam_src subdirectory of Boost. Then, copy the resulting bjam executable some place convenient_

Comment: @Tarek : What aspect of running build.sh are you stuck on? It's merely a matter of running a shell script... :-/